# Logging with Application Insights, something real time for debugging

Tags: azure, logging

I am using Application Insights for logging, and it takes several minutes to show there in Azure.

I am looking for a solution which I can use to write instantly into database once error happens.

Also "object reference not set to an object" really doesn't help if it throws an error in line where you are creating new object from parameter in previous object, when it is null, because you don't know which object is null.

Example:

```
        var logPaymentModel = new LogPaymentModel
        {
            Amount = package.Price,
            PackageId = package.Id,
            PaymentProviderId = provider.Id,
            UserSettingId = userSetting.Id,
            Token = model.Token
        };
```

Error here throws for 1 line, and you don't know which object is null. So should I change this code or is there any logger which shows better what is the issue? So also interested how to efficiently track null reference error in code to avoid confusion. Are object creation like this an issue? I am usually using automapper, and this code is test code, but in case of automapper mapping is in one line, and you really don't know again which object is null if exception is thrown in 1 line. So how to really track down which object is null in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can view a live stream in Application Insights which will show you the error (almost) instantly.

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-live-stream) for more details.

As for the Null Reference errors, I would personally change the code and throw an exception (ArgumentNullException probably) if some required object (package, provider or userSettings) is null.

Comment: Writing argumentnullexception every time is wrong, I was looking for some specific generic way

Comment: There is some work being done for that in VS which you can see here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/25
Not sure why you say writing ArgumentNullException every time is wrong, if it simply to much work you could use a simple Guard to ease the pain, here's a super light one: https://github.com/adamralph/liteguard/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Within application insights, you may Use Log Stream, which is basically live events and all the logs.

As for your example and null reference. depending on if your framework is compatible . how about using just package?.price . This shall handle your nulls with null propagation operator from c# 6